# Is there any way to use the Google Shamsi calendar in programming?

Tags: c#, calendar

Google recently added Shamsi calendar to its calendar service and I was wondering is there any way to use it in C# programming?

Answer (score 1):

There seem to exist a Persian calendar class in .NET, if that's your framework: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

There are extensive C# examples on that page.